# WP 8 Maps - custom pushpins not showing

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, maps, pushpin

I have serious problem with putting custom pushpins to native map. I'm loading map, getting user locations, zoom and center map on that location. After that I load locations around that point and put custom push pin (bitmap image). There can be more type of locations so that images are changed depending on different type. On initial load all works fine, but then I have  event on moving around map. So when move, I dynamically getting more locations, and putting more pins. But here comes problem. After initial putting pins, all after that pins are only visible of same colors as one putted on initial. I debug every line, and all seems to works as should, but pushpins of some another types aren't visible.

Here is code sample of putting pins:

```
Image slika = new Image();
        BitmapImage  myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/markers/test_1.png", UriKind.Relative));

        slika.Source = myBitmapImage;

        slika.Tag = test.id.ToString();
        slika.Height = 45;
        slika.Width = 45;
        slika.Opacity = 50;
        slika.Tap += slika_Tap;

        GeoCoordinate testGeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(test.latitude, test.longitude);

        MapOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MapOverlay();

        myLocationOverlay.Content = slika;

        myLocationOverlay.PositionOrigin = new System.Windows.Point(0.5, 0.5);
        myLocationOverlay.GeoCoordinate = testGeoCoordinate;

        MapLayer myLocationLayer = new MapLayer();
        myLocationLayer.Add(myLocationOverlay);
                 this.mapYourLocation2.Layers.Add(myLocationLayer);
```

Where comes to problem?